# Responsive video not showing correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my videos to show reponsive on a webpage. I managed to get the responsive part to work but initially it leaves a big space after my videos.

I've managed to tailor the CSS so it doesn't leave a gap by adding height and width to the iframe CSS code but now the videos are showing up too big. I really need them to be smaller.

Any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong?

I'm only using CSS and HTML.

Thank you!

HTML:

```
<div class="video-responsive">

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ru0K8uYEZWw?ecver=2" width="640"  height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>

<h1> TEST THIS SPACE </h1>
```

CSS:

```
 /* used to make embeded videos responsive within project */

 .video-responsive {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.video-responsive iframe {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote is okay, meaning it will cover the entire container the iframe is in, but I don't think this is best. Videos have an aspect ratio of 16:99full hd) so you won't be able to always cover the site vertically. Do you have extra info abotu what you actually need to do in here?

Comment: hope this helps [Space after video](https://jsfiddle.net/Tfa_chicky/p4wd00ox/).

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/Tfa_chicky/0zcvgqmf/) is the example where there's no space but the video is showing to large.

Comment: For the Fiddle with space after the video, try to use this CSS for the .video-responsive container. 
css: 
`.video-responsive {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 360px;
    max-width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Thanks so much @ManuelCheța. Seems to do he trick. You made my week!